# in-place subtraction in Cupy with broadcasting

Tags: cupy

Let's say I want to do this:

```
a=cp.zeros((10,10,50))
b=cp.ones((10,10,1))
a[:]=a-b
```

Is it possible to carry out the subtraction operation without additional  memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid in-place operation in all Python libraries (if supported), including NumPy and CuPy:

```
a -= b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe that the broadcasting involved leads to additional memory usage in cupy, at least it appears to be since I get a memory error, when executing. It should be possible to execute this without additional memory usage